Problem in Xcrysden GUI
When I open Xcrysden in WSL the GUI shows some weird noisy lines, making it difficult to use. Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Hello and welcome to MMSE! This looks like your issue is not directly related to matter modeling but you are having this SDL issue. Many people reported that restarting wsl and/or updating the packages solved this issue for them, i.e., (sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade and wsl --shutdown && wsl)

Thank you so much for your help. But after following what you said the problem still exists. I'll try to look for other solutions.
